# rsync + find -> local server to remote - copying full path

Tags: shell, sed, find, rsync, remote-server

running out of option, maybe rsync is not what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to synch two folder (local to remote) with somes options (time, ... )

Here the example :
Server A : /pathA/pathAA/folderToSynch/... (... files and folder)
Server B : /pathB/pathBB/folderTarget/...

I tried multiple test :

```
#1 rsync -auvzr -e "ssh -p ${port} -i ${pathFileRsa}" --files-from=<(find $pathSource -mmin -$timeMinFrom \( -type f -name "*.php" -o -type f -name "*.js" -o -type f -name "*.css" \) | sed "s,${pathSource}/,,g") $pathSource "${loginRemote}@${ipRemote}:${pathCible}"
#2 rsync -auvzrR -e "ssh -p ${port} -i ${pathFileRsa}" --files-from=<(find $pathSource -mmin -$timeMinFrom \( -type f -name "*.php" -o -type f -name "*.js" -o -type f -name "*.css" \) | sed "s,${pathSource}/,,g") $pathSource "${loginRemote}@${ipRemote}:${pathCible}"
#3 rsync -auvzr -e "ssh -p ${port} -i ${pathFileRsa}" --files-from=<(find $pathSource -mmin -$timeMinFrom \( -type f -name "*.php" -o -type f -name "*.js" -o -type f -name "*.css" \) | sed "s,${pathSource}/,,g") / "${loginRemote}@${ipRemote}:${pathCible}"
...
```

And tryed almost all combinaison with option -rR... removing with sed or no part of folder etc and the best I got was :
/pathB/pathBB/folderTarget/pathA/pathAA/folderToSynch/...

I'm trying to remove **pathA/pathAA/folderToSynch/** from server B.
Any idea how to do it or any other package for that

Regards